# Vifm. Edit file in opened gvim

Tags: vim, vifm

I use Gvim to write code. And use vifm to make file management ( copy, move files, extract tar's ). Sometimes, when navigating in vifm i need to open some file to edit him. Using `:e` it opened vim in same window. Is there any way to open file to edit in already opened gvim program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Vim's client-server feature to send the `:edit` to the existing GVIM instance. In the terminal Vim / vifm, execute:

```
:!gvim --remote path/to/file
```

See `:help remote.txt` for details. You can also open the file in a new tab page with `--remote-tab` etc.

Comment: I read "remote.txt" but not find answer to next question. I bind ":!gvim --remote %c" command to some key and now i can open file to edit very quickly. But i need to press N to get focus on Gvim. Can i do it automatically from vifm?

Comment: @user3583807: Please don't ask follow-up questions in the comments; submit a new (full) question.

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution/workaround (I'm using a mac fwiw):

In vfimrc, define

```
" yank current file path into the clipboard
nnoremap Cf :!echo -n %c:p | pbcopy %i<cr>
```

To copy filename and dir into system clipboard

Then in vifm, cursor over file and type

```
Cf
:!gvim "
<cmd-v>
```

to paste clipboard, 
and finish expression with...

```
"
<enter>
```

and now that file should open in gvim.  It worked for me